# when I call Tuya Smart API, how to resolve it if the calling interface has an error code: 1106, permission deny?

Tags: api, iot, tuya

I checked the device is paired with Tuya Smart App, and then use the device Id in Tuya Smart APP for control; I confirm the Id of the device to be controlled is correct.

Answer (score 1):

there are 3 different api explorer calls to retrieve the status, only one works for me: https://openapi.tuyaeu.com/v1.1/iot-03/ (General Device Management -> Get Device Information)

Answer (score 0):

I tried it a few times with the engineer，there are several situations:

1. The device to be controlled is not an OEM App created by the developer on the Tuya Open Platform; or the Tuya Smart APP is used to pair the device and then control the device through an interface call.
   solution:

1. First check if the device is paired with Tuya Smart APP, and then use the device Id in Tuya Smart APP for control;
2. Then check whether the Id of the device to be controlled is correct and whether it is from an OEM APP created by its own developer account or an APP developed based on the SDK;
3. In the end, you need to make sure that the device and product created by the OEM APP created under your developer account can be controlled through the cloud-cloud docking API call.

2. The device requested to be controlled has been removed, restored to factory settings, or re-configured to the network.
   solution:

1. If the device has been removed, please re-configure the network and add it in the APP;
2. Re-obtain the device list and refresh the device ids to be controlled.

3. Interface parameter passing error.
   solution:
   Check if the following parameters are correct：

1. The device id is wrong. Note that the device id is not uuid.
2. The area url is wrong. Pay attention to the area where the device is paired. At the same time, call the interface address of the corresponding area.